# View simpleschema mongodb collections

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm currently using simple schema to manage my mongodb designs. I'm at a point where i have a number of collections and it can be a little difficult to visualize all of the collections while adding features to the app. Is there a graphical way  to view the schema collections? Noob questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want but if you're looking for a mongodb gui client then you can try [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/). But it's not interconnected to the simple schema package except if you're using [collections2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly view the schemas of a collection until you have inserted a document.

I will advice seeding the collection with some sample data and then using `meteortoys:allthings` package to view the collections. (More info [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteortoys/allthings))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and it's a great solution however I was hoping for something that didn't require me to add in data to the collection. `meteortoys:allthings` is a fantastic tool though. Thanks